# What makes lengthOf inefficient in lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I noticed this [remark](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/commit/cdd89717877e628f4b18f82e8e504d83dd4ea32b) in `lens` claiming that `lengthOf` can be "rather inefficient":

```
-- /Note:/ This can be rather inefficient for large containers [...]
lengthOf :: Getting (Endo (Endo Int)) s a -> s -> Int
lengthOf l = foldlOf' l (\a _ -> a + 1) 0
```

Can it be asymptocically inefficient? Can it leak space despite being strict left fold or does GHC generate too much "busywork" code?

Comment: Well it runs in *linear* time, which is typically quite long to calculate the length.

Answer (score 2):

*Update:*  See below -- the poor performance of `lengthOf` seems to be just lack of specialization to the list case when benchmarking.

As @WillemVanOnsem indicates, I think the comment is mostly referring to the fact that this particular approach -- of running through the elements of the container with a counter -- will be inefficient for containers that have some other method of returning a length.  For example, for a very large vector `v`, you could technically use `lengthOf traverse v`, but `Data.Vector.length v` will be much faster.

On the other hand, `lengthOf` *can be* quite inefficient for, say, counting the elements in a list.  The following benchmark:

```
import Criterion.Main
import Control.Lens

l :: [Int]
l = replicate 1000000 123

main = defaultMain
  [ bench "Prelude.length"        $ whnf length l
  , bench "Control.Lens.lengthOf" $ whnf (lengthOf traverse) l
  ]
```

shows that `length` is about 15 times faster than `lengthOf`.  (I used GHC 8.4.3 with `-O2` for all my tests.)

Note that this difference isn't a result of list fusion (since there's no fusion in the `Prelude.length` case when the `whnf` call is used).

It's actually a result of specialization of the code to lists.  Even though `Prelude.length` is applicable to any `Foldable`, the instance for lists uses a list-specific implementation that's essentially equivalent to:

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength xs = lenAcc xs 0
  where lenAcc [] n = n
        lenAcc (_:ys) n = lenAcc ys (n+1)
```

(I didn't check for sure that this was the implementation being used, but `myLength` had nearly equivalent performance to `Data.List`.)

The Core for `myLength` uses unboxed integers in a loop that directly pattern matches the list constructors, more or less like:

```
lenAcc
  = \xs n ->
      case xs of
        [] -> n
        (:) _ xs' -> lenAcc xs' (+# n 1#)
```

It turned out that if I used `lengthOf` in a more realistic program with ample room to specialize to a list in the same way:

```
import Control.Lens

l :: [Int]
{-# NOINLINE l #-}
l = replicate 1000000 123

myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength = lengthOf traverse

main = print (myLength l)
```

it generated Core like the following.  The same as above with an extra parameter which was essentially a casting identity function:

```
lenAcc'
lenAcc'
  = \n id' xs ->
      case xs of {
        [] -> id' (I# n);
        (:) _ xs' -> lenAcc' (+# n 1#) id' xs'
      }
```

I wasn't able to benchmark it, but it would probably be plenty fast.

So, `lengthOf traverse` is capable of being optimized to be almost as fast as `Prelude.length`, but depending on how it's used, it might end up using a really inefficient implementation.